# Web Scraping using beautifulsoup (error in For Loop)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python programming, trying to do web scraping just for learning using Beautifulsoup, applying an iterator using FOR Loop, but I guess it is running only for the one time, and the next time it is showing me some error, tried a lot but was not able to resolve.

Below is my Code -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://www.packtpub.com/all'

page = urlopen(url)
soup_packtpage = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
page.close()

all_book = soup_packtpage.find_all("div",class_='book-block-outer')

for book_title in all_book:
    title = book_title.div['data-product-title']
    price = book_title.div['data-product-price']
    category = book_title.div['data-product-category']
    print(title)
    print("Rs:-"+ price)
    print(category)
```

and below is the output -

Learn Algorithms and Data Structures in Java for Day-to-Day Applications [Video]
Rs:-199.44
Application Development

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/bhagwatanimesh/PycharmProjects/packet_pub/packet_pub", line 17, in 
>       title = book_title.div['data-product-title']
>     File "/home/bhagwatanimesh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1011, in **getitem**
>       return self.attrs[key]
>   KeyError: 'data-product-title'

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, You are trying to access a key which is not present in the dictionary. 
For solving this you may use below code.

```
for book_title in all_book:
    try:
        title = book_title.div['data-product-title']
        price = book_title.div['data-product-price']
        category = book_title.div['data-product-category']
        print(title)
        print("Rs:-"+ price)
        print(category)
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was trying it from a long time and I was unable to solve it, now it is working fine :)
Thanks a lot :)